# Building a c# desktop app, starting from scratch, tips please

Tags: c#, layout

I need to build a simple desktop app, my experience is with vb6 but it's time to move on, so i need some help.
My app is relatively simple, a db table that holds events by date.
The app should display the events on a full screen in the following structure:

1. first line - todays events, a single event every time, rotating.
2. second line - the closest events (7 days a head), 5 every time, rotating.
3. third line - all other events , in ..rotation..
   each event will be held in a "box", with constant (by percentage) size..

The problems I anticipate are:
The layout, how can i keep it aesthetic, the line heights, the events boxes? (in vb i used to attach it to the resize event and then calculate the size)

so, please - any tips? ideas?
where to start ?
what should i google?

Comment: I think this is either an important question that should get 20+ upvotes, or a duplicate.

Comment: since your starting from scratch, one tip - use EF4 for the persistence. L2SQL is (basically) obsolete. Some people prefer to build the domain model first, do it with TDD, make sure you can do basic persistence operations, and *then* build your presentation. Then again if you only have 1 table - maybe EF is overkill.

Comment: Is your question specifically regarding GUI applications, or about C# in general? These are very different questions.

Comment: ripper: I want to work with c# and to use its GUI abilities, so.. both?! (note that i am new to .NET)
RPM, thanks - i really have only one table with very simple records, so an overkill will be my non-overkill :)

Comment: @yossi - in light of the answers already given here, I edited the title to be specifically about desktop apps. I suggest you ask another question about general C# tips (post a link here please).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first need to decide if you're going to use WPF or WinForms, because everything else follows from that.

Winforms will feel more like VB6, but is not the latest and greatest thing.

WPF will be harder to learn to start with, but then stuff like all your layout resizing will just work, without you needing to write any of that calculating code.

Silverlight is (loosely) a subset of WPF, and if I was starting with no prior knowledge today, I might be inclined to use that.

The Adam Nathan book is excellent for WPF, not sure which book I'd recommend for Silverlight.

Comment: "but then stuff like all your layout resizing will just work, without you needing to write any of that calculating code" - using Anchor/Dock and containers (GroupBox, Panel, etc) you also don't need to write layouting code when using WinForms.

Comment: Well, there's something in what you say, but it's not really in the same league as WPF for fluid layouts.

Answer (score 2):

> The layout, how can i keep it aesthetic, the line heights, the events boxes?

Take a look at the TableLayoutPanel (WinForms).